# I am getting these warnings everytime I click a button and call other .js components

Tags: reactjs, warnings

I am getting these warnings everytime I click a button and call other .js components. I need to know what need to be done to eliminate this warnings.

```
index.js:1 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <th> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
    in th (at Welcome.js:19)
    in Welcome (at Main.js:145)
    in StepForm (at App.js:8)
    in div (at App.js:7)
    in div (at App.js:6)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

Comment: Could you add the html as well of you code, I think you are trying to add tr as a div child which is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th

> Permitted parents:  A `<tr>` element

This means in your JSX, `<th>` needs to be the direct child of a `<tr>` element.

```
<tr>
  <th>...</th>
</tr>
```